# What is the difference between Investor and Altruist?

Tags: discussion, badges

As I have unlocked the ability to place a Bounty, I have applied one to someone else's question, which earned me the [Investor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/219/investor) badge, description reading `First bounty you offer on another person's question`. Now, there is a badge that is confusing me, [Altruist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist) is another badge with the description `First bounty you manually award on another person's question`. So, in these two badges, what is the difference between the words "you offer" and "you manually award"?

Comment: You offer a bounty before you can award it. Offering involves “paying” reputation points as a bounty; awarding involves someone actually receiving these reputation points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the "Investor" for first starting a bounty on another person's question and the "Altruist" after you've given the rep to someone.

To get all the 4 bounty-related badges costs at least 100 rep, but there is no easier way to do that.

Choose wisely the questions.